# Find all Children where Parent and Grandparent meet certain condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model relationships:

```
class Author
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I have boolean columns "active" for Authors and "published" for Posts.

I want to find all comments where author.active: true and post.published: true

Could anyone help me out?  I'm able to get all Posts from an Author with author.active: true by using a joins statement (this code in the Post model):

```
joins(:author).where(authors: {active: true})
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to get all comments where author.active: true and post.published: true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Comment.joins(:post => :author).where("authors.active = true AND posts.published = true" )
```

or

```
Comment.joins(:post => :author).where(:post => {:published => true, :author => {:active => true}})
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the joins hash syntax that was messing me up!